# CloudPageURL not passing any parameters to LandingPage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

I need to pass parameters from an email to a landing page. In the past , I have used the CloudPagesURL function.

For some reason, it doesnt seem to be passing the parameters this time.

Here is the ampscript from my email:

```
href="%%=Redirectto(CloudPagesURL(4554,'DateAdded',@ConfirmationDate,'value_1',
@Value1,'value_2',@Value2,'value_3',@Value3,'value_4',@Value4,'value_5',@Value5
,'email_name',@EmailName,'user_email',@EmailAddress,'ip_address',@IP,'audience_size',@AudienceSize,'confirmed','confirmed'))=%%"
```

For the landing page,

```
%%[


@DoubleOptinDate = RequestParameter(emailaddr)
@DoubleOptInValue1 = RequestParameter("value_1")

]%%

Success!!

%%=v(@DoubleOptinDate)=%%
%%=v(@DoubleOptInValue1)=%%
```

Unfortunately , none of the variables are printed. I will appreciate any pointers on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the value of a variable, use the keyword SET.

```
SET @DoubleOptinDate = RequestParameter("emailaddr")
SET @DoubleOptInValue1 = RequestParameter("value_1")
```

**Reference:**
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm