# Personalization String to HTML value

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, html, ssjs

I'm trying to pass a personalization string of %%emailaddr%% to a value of a textbox. I've tried using SSJS and AMPscript but it doesn't seem to be working for me unless I have the wrong syntax. I am just looking to use this email value freely throughout the whole HTML page in CloudPages

Here is my attempt:

```
%%[

 VAR @email
 SET @email = emailaddr

]%%

<script runat="server">
var email = Variable.GetValue("@email");
</script>
```

Then I would try to put it in a table tag.

```
        <script runat="server">
          Write("<td width='155' valign='bottom'><input type='text' name='Name1' value=' " + email + " ' id='Name1' /></td>");
        </script>
```

My syntax might just be off, but is there a problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

This wont work on a cloud page as the `emailaddr` personalisation string only works in emails. What you can do is pass this attribute (or retrieve it from) the subscriber context from an email.

References:

- [CloudPageURL not passing any parameters to LandingPage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220102/cloudpageurl-not-passing-any-parameters-to-landingpage)
- [Cloud Pages URL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm)

Comment: How would you go about grabbing it from the context? Do you mean from like a URL standpoint?

Comment: Yes or you can . Either from a form pass or by passing them in the query strings of a cloud page

Comment: Doesn't this allow for the email just to be changed within the parameters at the top? Or is there a way to like encrypt that.

Comment: if you use the CloudPagesURL() function , that it will pass the email in an encyrpted string. You can pick this up with the RequestParameter() function

Comment: I guess for a little more detail, this is being used to build a custom profile center and I just have the profile center link clicking to a cloudpage that I have built. How would I be able to integrate using the CloudPageURL() function while doing that?

Comment: For a bit more detail, visit here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm